# Javascript - Fast reload a DIV (containing php codes)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need a javascript code which refresh an HTML DIV.
Currently, i use this:

```
$("#area").load("something.html #area > *");
```

It is good, it makes what i need, but i have to call it every 1 second and it takes about 4-5 seconds to reload my DIV. Is there any way to reload a DIV (the DIV contains php codes) fast?

Comment: What does something.html do? Can you post some of the code?

Comment: is something.html local or remote? how is it populated?

Comment: <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
    $("#main-map").load("map.php #main-map > *");
    }, 2000);
    });
    </script> That's full code which loads my DIV. You can check my website page here: http://www.movie.b-zone.ro/map.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here relies on your PHP server, you can perform a `.load` call, a `$.post` call or an `$.ajax` call and I believe all will have the same result. The 4-5 seconds you are describing are mostly due to something in the server side script that's taking long to process. My suggestion would be to check the `map.php` file (as per your comment) and try to improve the performance of it.

Comment: You are right. I deleted some code which takes some information from my SA:MP server, and now the DIV is reloading instantly. Sorry for bad english and thanks for advice.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help you out :)